# asp.net click event not firing up

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm having trouble with a `Button` . The Click event is not working, i'm adding this button to a cell on a table. The rows for the table are filled from a List. It's a simple project for college. I'm already using this code on a previous page and it works.

Here's my code:

aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<!-- Nombre del Cliente -->
<asp:Label ID="lblNombreCliente" CssClass="lbl negrita fs30" runat="server" Text="Cliente: " />
<!-- Listado de Proyectos-->
<asp:Table ID="tblProyectos" CssClass="tbl" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="th w10">Cod</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="th">Nombre</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="th w10">Horas</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="th w20">Encargado</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="th">Ver</asp:TableHeaderCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

CS:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int codCliente = 0;

            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Usuario Conectado
                string nombre = Request.Params["usuario"];

                if (nombre != null)
                {
                    this.Master.datosUsuario = String.Format(nombre);
                }

                //Codigo Cliente
                codCliente = int.Parse(Request.Params["codCliente"]);
                if (codCliente != 0) 
                {
                    foreach (Cliente objCliente in listaClientes)
                    {
                        if (objCliente.Cod_cliente == codCliente)
                        {
                            lblNombreCliente.Text = objCliente.Nombre;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }//fin isPostBack

                //Se agregan proyectos a la tbl
                int i = 1;
                foreach (Proyecto item in listaProyectos)
                {
                    //Se rellenan las celdas
                    if (item.Cod_cliente == codCliente)
                    {
                        TableRow fila = new TableRow();
                        TableCell cod = new TableCell();
                        TableCell nombre_proyecto = new TableCell();
                        TableCell horas = new TableCell();
                        TableCell encargado = new TableCell();
                        TableCell btnsProyecto = new TableCell();

                        string nombre_encargado = string.Empty;

                        foreach (Usuario usu in listaUsuarios)
                        {
                            if(usu.Cod_usuario == item.Cod_encargado){
                                nombre_encargado = usu.Nombre;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        Button btnIngreso = new Button();
                        btnIngreso.CssClass = "btn";
                        btnIngreso.Text = "Ingresar";
                        btnIngreso.ID = "btnIngresar_" + i;
                        btnIngreso.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnIngresar_Click);
                        btnsProyecto.Controls.Add(btnIngreso);

                        cod.Text = item.Cod_proyecto.ToString();
                        nombre_proyecto.Text = item.Nombre_proyecto;
                        horas.Text = item.Horas.ToString();
                        encargado.Text = nombre_encargado;

                        //Se agregan las celdas
                        fila.Cells.Add(cod);
                        fila.Cells.Add(nombre_proyecto);
                        fila.Cells.Add(horas);
                        fila.Cells.Add(encargado);
                        fila.Cells.Add(btnsProyecto);

                        tblProyectos.Rows.Add(fila);
                        i++;
                    }

                }//fin foreach tbl


        }//fin page_load

        protected void btnIngresar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            int fila = int.Parse(btn.ID.Substring(btn.ID.Length - 1));
            int codProyecto = int.Parse(tblProyectos.Rows[fila].Cells[0].Text);
            string url = String.Format("{0}?codProyecto={1}&usuario={2}"
                                        , "IngresoMantencion.aspx"
                                        , codProyecto, this.objUsuario.Nombre);
            Response.Redirect(url);
        }
```

I'm from Chile, that's why my code has spanish words. I hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot see anywhere in your aspx or code where a `Button` asp control is being created. Have you left something out of your question?

Comment: yes, sorry. I forgot the Button part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is called `Button btnIngreso = new Button();` but you call `protected void btnIngresar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)`
Rename the handler to `protected void btnIngreso_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)` and see if it works.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: It didn't worked. I added a breakpoint at `protected void btnIngreso_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)` and it doesn't get in.

Comment: The other thing I was wondering about is the button id. It calls it "btnIngresar_" + i; I'm assuming i is the index of the row the button is in. Could that maybe have to do with the fact that it's not getting in? Maybe the handler needs to know the id?

Comment: i don't think that is the problem. I use exactly the same steps on the previous page and it works. Don't know what the problem is...

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you @campagnolo_1 , Actually i didn't solved it, instead of adding a `Click` event on the button, i used a `PostBackUrl`.

Comment: How do i marked this question as solved? i just mark @campagnolo_1 answer as correct?

Comment: That's up to you. It wasn't really correct, but you can upvote it as helpful if you like.

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out!